# DataGridTextColumn.IsReadOnly seems to be faulty

Tags: .net, wpf, datagrid

If I create a binding to the `IsReadOnly` property of the `DataGridTextColumn`, it does not actualize. If I set it through markup, it works.

```xml
<DataGridTextColumn IsReadOnly="{Binding IsReferenceInactive}"/> <!-- NOP --> 

<DataGridTextColumn IsReadOnly="True"/> <!-- Works as expected, cell is r/o -->
```

The `IsReferenceInactive` property is a DP and works fine (For testing purposes I've bound it to a checkbox, that worked)

Is this a known limitation?

**Update**

Uups,  other than I wrote, there is a message in the output window:

> System.Windows.Data Error: 2 : Cannot find governing FrameworkElement or FrameworkContentElement for target element. BindingExpression:Path=IsReferenceInactive; DataItem=null; target element is 'DataGridTextColumn' (HashCode=23836176); target property is 'IsReadOnly' (type 'Boolean')

Comment: It seems that link to Microsoft Connect in Update section has been retired
since january 2022. Please, update or remove the link.

Answer (score 39, accepted):

Same as codekaizen but simpler:

```
<DataGridTextColumn>
  <DataGridTextColumn.CellStyle>
    <Style>
      <Setter Property="UIElement.IsEnabled" Value="{Binding IsEditable}" />
    </Style>
  </DataGridTextColumn.CellStyle>
</DataGridTextColumn>
```

Comment: This is the best (and should marked as the Accepted) Answer, since it: a) maintains original display/editing formats, b) not specific to display and editing sub-Elements *and* c) is the simplest!

Comment: The `UIElement.IsEnabled` also makes the cell unselectable, meaning that such columns cannot be naviaged on keyboard and their values cannot be copied to clipboard.

Answer (score 18):

`DataGridColumn`s are not part of the visual tree, and don't participate in binding like this. The way I get around it is to use `DataGridTemplateColumn`.

```
<DataGridTemplateColumn>
    <DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <TextBlock Text="{Binding Path=myProperty}" />
        </DataTemplate>
    </DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
    <DataGridTemplateColumn.CellEditingTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <TextBox IsEnabled="{Binding Path=myBool}" Text="{Binding Path=myProperty, Mode=TwoWay}" />
        </DataTemplate>
    </DataGridTemplateColumn.CellEditingTemplate>
</DataGridTemplateColumn>
```

There are other workarounds, which I've found a bit too hackish, but they do work; to wit: [Link](https://web.archive.org/web/20160227001645/http://blogs.msdn.com:80/b/jaimer/archive/2008/11/22/forwarding-the-datagrid-s-datacontext-to-its-columns.aspx)

Comment: Ok, eventually I remarked it also. I have not looked good enough in the output window. Sorry, I posted to fast. But I dont't will delete the question, perhaps it will help someone who also was in a hurry:)

Comment: No problem; it gives more fodder for Google/Bing to find the right answer when questions are asked on SO.

Comment: @hansmaad's Answer (at " https://stackoverflow.com/a/18657986/401246 ") is the best (and should marked as the Accepted) Answer, since it: a) maintains original display/editing formats, b) is not specific to display and editing sub-Elements *and* c) is the simplest!

Answer (score 8):

I found this solution which allows you to bind to data when the DataContext is not inherited:
http://www.thomaslevesque.com/2011/03/21/wpf-how-to-bind-to-data-when-the-datacontext-is-not-inherited/

Add the `BindingProxy` class Thomas wrote and add this resource to your `DataGrid`:

```
<DataGrid.Resources>
    <local:BindingProxy x:Key="proxy" Data="{Binding}" />
</DataGrid.Resources>
```

Now you can bind to your `DataContex` via the `Data` property of the `BindingProxy` just as you would expect.

```
<DataGridTextColumn Header="Price"
                    Binding="{Binding Price}"
                    IsReadOnly="{Binding Data.LockFields, Source={StaticResource proxy}}"/>
```

Answer (score 1):

If you've used EditingElementStyle and need to change IsEnabled value by Binding:

```
    <DataGridTextColumn
        MinWidth="100"
        MaxWidth="250"
        Binding="{Binding MessageText, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}"
        ElementStyle="{StaticResource TextBlockStyle}"
        Header="Message Text">
        <DataGridTextColumn.EditingElementStyle>
            <Style BasedOn="{StaticResource TextBoxStyle}" TargetType="TextBox">
                <Setter Property="IsEnabled" Value="{Binding IsEnabledMessage}" />
            </Style>
        </DataGridTextColumn.EditingElementStyle>
    </DataGridTextColumn>
```

Answer (score 0):

The Binding of the DataGridTextColumn works only for the Text property, but not for the other properties of DataGridTextColumn.

**Solution:**
DataGridTextColumn tells the DataGrid to create a TextBlock for every row and that column. You can define a style for TextBlock and link the Style with the Style.Key to the TextBlock of that column (ElementStyle).

Of course, the TextBlock needs now to find the object from the datalist. It can do that with a RelativeSource Binding with the AncestorType=DataGridRow. The DataGridRow then provides access to the object.

Something like this:

```
<Window.Resources>
  <Style x:Key="IsReadOnlyStyle" TargetType="TextBlock">
    <Setter Property="IsReadOnly" 
      Value="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType={x:Type DataGridRow}}, 
      Path =Item.NoOutput/>
  </Style>
</Window.Resources>

<DataGrid>
  <DataGrid.Columns>
    <DataGridTextColumn Header="Value" Width="*" Binding="{Binding Value}" ElementStyle="{StaticResource IsReadOnlyStyle}"/>
</DataGrid.Columns>
```

Complicated right ? I recommend you to read my detailed article about datagrid formatting at:
http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/683429/Guide-to-WPF-DataGrid-formatting-using-bindings?msg=5037235#xx5037235xx

Good luck, you need it :-)

Comment: This solution does not work. TextBlock does not have an IsReadOnly property. TextBox has that property, but it can only be used with EditingElementStyle, which produces visually different results.

Answer (score 0):

If you like @codekaizen's solution but will have the look of a disabled TextBox, then this will do the trick:

```
<DataGridTemplateColumn>
    <DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <TextBox IsEnabled="{Binding Path=myBool}" Text="{Binding Path=myProperty}" />
        </DataTemplate>
    </DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
    <DataGridTemplateColumn.CellEditingTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <TextBox IsEnabled="{Binding Path=myBool}" Text="{Binding Path=myProperty, Mode=TwoWay}" />
        </DataTemplate>
    </DataGridTemplateColumn.CellEditingTemplate>
</DataGridTemplateColumn>
```

Answer (score 0):

I've found a nice solution to use DataGridColumns with binding by using a MarkupExtension. This way Bindings with converters could be used: https://stackoverflow.com/a/27465022/9758687