# DataGridTextColumn Visibility Binding

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, wpfdatagrid

I'm trying to bind column visibility to that of another element like this:

```
<Window x:Class="WpfApplication1.MainWindow"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    Title="MainWindow" Height="350" Width="525">
<Window.Resources>
    <BooleanToVisibilityConverter x:Key="BooleanToVisibilityConverter" />
</Window.Resources>
<StackPanel>
    <CheckBox x:Name="chkColumnVisible" Content="Show column" />
    <DataGrid x:Name="MyDataGrid" AutoGenerateColumns="False">
        <DataGrid.Columns>
            <DataGridTextColumn Header="Column1" Visibility="{Binding ElementName=chkColumnVisible, Path=IsChecked, Converter={StaticResource BooleanToVisibilityConverter}}"/>
        </DataGrid.Columns>
    </DataGrid>
</StackPanel>
```

but I get this error in VS output:

```
System.Windows.Data Error: 2 : Cannot find governing FrameworkElement or FrameworkContentElement for target element. BindingExpression:Path=IsChecked; DataItem=null; target element is 'DataGridTextColumn' (HashCode=48860040); target property is 'Visibility' (type 'Visibility')
```

Is there a pure XAML way to accomplish this?

Answer (score 46, accepted):

The columns of a `DataGrid` are abstract objects not appearing in the visual or logical tree. You cannot use `ElementName` and `RelativeSource`. `Source` in combination with [`x:Reference`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee795380.aspx) should work though:

```xml
Visibility="{Binding Source={x:Reference chkColumnVisible},
                     Path=IsChecked,
                     Converter={StaticResource BooleanToVisibilityConverter}}"
```

Comment: Thank you, it works!  But so that I can sleep :)... I can definitely understand why RelativeSource wouldn't work, since it is relative to the target.  But what on earth is the problem with ElementName?? I thought I was giving the binding an absolute source by using ElementName (and obviously I'm wrong!) so it wouldn't matter if the target is on the visual or logical tree or not.

Comment: @ErenErsonmez: `ElementName` uses the current namescope to resolve the name, and namescopes are dependant on the trees as far as i know.

Comment: @ErenErsonmez: [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.data.binding.elementname.aspx): `You can refer to elements in code only if they are registered to the appropriate NameScope through RegisterName. For more information, see `[`WPF XAML Namescopes`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms746659.aspx) -> `The names in a XAML namescope can be used to establish relationships between the XAML-defined names of objects and their instance equivalents in an object tree.`

Comment: Thank you! I knew there had to be a much better answer other than using a proxy element.

Answer (score 15):

I wrote a markupextension for it:

```
using System;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Linq;
using System.Reflection;
using System.Windows;
using System.Windows.Data;
using System.Windows.Markup;
using System.Xaml;

/// <summary>
/// Binds to the datacontext of the current root object or ElementName
/// </summary>
[MarkupExtensionReturnType(typeof(object))]
public class NinjaBinding : MarkupExtension
{
    private static readonly DependencyObject DependencyObject = new DependencyObject();
    private static readonly string[] DoNotCopy = { "Path", "Source", "ElementName", "RelativeSource", "ValidationRules" };
    private static readonly PropertyInfo[] CopyProperties = typeof(Binding).GetProperties().Where(x => !DoNotCopy.Contains(x.Name)).ToArray();
    public NinjaBinding()
    {
    }

    public NinjaBinding(Binding binding)
    {
        Binding = binding;
    }

    public Binding Binding { get; set; }

    private bool IsInDesignMode
    {
        get { return DesignerProperties.GetIsInDesignMode(DependencyObject); }
    }

    public override object ProvideValue(IServiceProvider serviceProvider)
    {
        if (Binding == null)
        {
            throw new ArgumentException("Binding == null");
        }
        if (IsInDesignMode)
        {
            return DefaultValue(serviceProvider);
        }
        Binding binding = null;
        if (Binding.ElementName != null)
        {
            var reference = new Reference(Binding.ElementName);
            var source = reference.ProvideValue(serviceProvider);
            if (source == null)
            {
                throw new ArgumentException("Could not resolve element");
            }
            binding = CreateElementNameBinding(Binding, source);
        }
        else if (Binding.RelativeSource !=null)
        {
            throw new ArgumentException("RelativeSource not supported");
        }
        else
        {
            var rootObjectProvider = (IRootObjectProvider)serviceProvider.GetService(typeof(IRootObjectProvider));
            if (rootObjectProvider == null)
            {
                throw new ArgumentException("rootObjectProvider == null");
            }
            binding = CreateDataContextBinding((FrameworkElement) rootObjectProvider.RootObject, Binding);
        }

        var provideValue = binding.ProvideValue(serviceProvider);
        return provideValue;
    }

    private static Binding CreateElementNameBinding(Binding original, object source)
    {
        var binding = new Binding()
         {
             Path = original.Path,
             Source = source,
         };
        SyncProperties(original, binding);
        return binding;
    }

    private static Binding CreateDataContextBinding(FrameworkElement rootObject, Binding original)
    {
        string path = string.Format("{0}.{1}", FrameworkElement.DataContextProperty.Name, original.Path.Path);
        var binding = new Binding(path)
         {
             Source = rootObject,
         };
        SyncProperties(original, binding);
        return binding;
    }

    private static void SyncProperties(Binding source, Binding target)
    {
        foreach (var copyProperty in CopyProperties)
        {
            var value = copyProperty.GetValue(source);
            copyProperty.SetValue(target, value);
        }
        foreach (var rule in source.ValidationRules)
        {
            target.ValidationRules.Add(rule);
        }
    }

    private static object DefaultValue(IServiceProvider serviceProvider)
    {
        var provideValueTarget = (IProvideValueTarget)serviceProvider.GetService(typeof(IProvideValueTarget));
        if (provideValueTarget == null)
        {
            throw new ArgumentException("provideValueTarget == null");
        }
        var dependencyProperty = (DependencyProperty)provideValueTarget.TargetProperty;
        return dependencyProperty.DefaultMetadata.DefaultValue;
    }
}
```

It enables binding to the DataContext of the current root object {Window, UserControl, ...}

Sample usage (Visible & Visibility are properties of the ViewModel):

```
<DataGrid>
    <DataGrid.Columns>
        <DataGridTextColumn Header="DataContext" Visibility="{dataGridBox:NinjaBinding Binding={Binding Visibility}}" />
        <DataGridTextColumn Header="Converter" Visibility="{dataGridBox:NinjaBinding Binding={Binding Visible, Converter={StaticResource BooleanToVisibilityConverter}}}" />
        <DataGridTextColumn Header="ElementName" Visibility="{dataGridBox:NinjaBinding Binding={Binding IsChecked, ElementName=CheckBox, Converter={StaticResource BooleanToVisibilityConverter}}}" />
    </DataGrid.Columns>
</DataGrid>
```

Comment: Does not work for me for some reason... `BindingExpression path error: 'ValidationColumnVisibility' property not found on 'object' ''NameFixupToken' (HashCode=55620207)'. BindingExpression:Path=ValidationColumnVisibility; DataItem='NameFixupToken' (HashCode=55620207); target element is 'DataGridTextColumn' (HashCode=62066456); target property is 'Visibility' (type 'Visibility')`

Comment: Worked perfecly with a DataTemplateColumn and DataGrid in my application.

Answer (score 1):

The solution from Johan Larsson works perfectly, only the FallbackValue from the Binding isn't forwarded, so I've changed it like this:

```cs
private object DefaultValue(IServiceProvider serviceProvider)
{
    if (Binding.FallbackValue != null)
        return Binding.FallbackValue;

    var provideValueTarget = (IProvideValueTarget)serviceProvider.GetService(typeof(IProvideValueTarget));
    if (provideValueTarget == null)
    {
        throw new ArgumentException("provideValueTarget == null");
    }
    var dependencyProperty = (DependencyProperty)provideValueTarget.TargetProperty;
    return dependencyProperty.DefaultMetadata.DefaultValue;
}
```

So it could be used like this, here for example for Binding to a Header:

```
<DataGridTemplateColumn Header="{dataGridBox:NinjaBinding Binding={Binding MyHeaderName1, FallbackValue=HeadingNr1}}" />
```