# Bind from ControlTemplate to ViewModel

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm, data-binding

I have stripped down my problem to a minimal example: My DataGrid is defined by a ControlTemplate and in that ControlTemplate I cannot bind to anything from my ViewModel.

This is the simplified ViewModel:

```
public class ViewModel : PropertyChangedBase
{
    private string text1;

    public ViewModel()
    {
        this.text1 = "tx1!";
    }

    public string Text1
    {
        get { return text1; }
        set
        {
            if (value == text1) return;
            text1 = value;
            NotifyOfPropertyChange(() => Text1);
        }
    }
}
```

I tried to bind to `Text1` with several methods. Most things I find via Google suggest `FindAncestor` but it did not work either:

```
<Window x:Class="DataGridTemplateBinding.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        xmlns:local="clr-namespace:DataGridTemplateBinding"
        Title="MainWindow" Height="350" Width="525"
        x:Name="LayoutRoot"
        >
    <Window.Resources>
        <ControlTemplate x:Key="TableTemplate">
            <DataGrid>
                <DataGrid.Columns>
                    <DataGridTextColumn Header="Column 1" />
                    <!-- by ElementName -->
                    <DataGridTextColumn Header="{Binding DataContext.Text1, ElementName=LayoutRoot}" />
                    <DataGridTextColumn Header="{Binding Text1, ElementName=LayoutRoot}" />

                    <!-- by Ancestor type (Window) -->
                    <DataGridTextColumn Header="{Binding DataContext.Text1, RelativeSource={RelativeSource FindAncestor, AncestorType={x:Type Window}}}" />
                    <DataGridTextColumn Header="{Binding Text1, RelativeSource={RelativeSource FindAncestor, AncestorType={x:Type Window}}}" />

                    <!-- by templated parent -->
                    <DataGridTextColumn Header="{Binding DataContext.Text1, RelativeSource={RelativeSource TemplatedParent}}" />
                    <DataGridTextColumn Header="{Binding Text1, RelativeSource={RelativeSource TemplatedParent}}" />

                    <!-- by self?? -->
                    <DataGridTextColumn Header="{Binding DataContext.Text1, RelativeSource={RelativeSource Self}}" />
                    <DataGridTextColumn Header="{Binding Text1, RelativeSource={RelativeSource Self}}" />

                    <DataGridTextColumn Header="{Binding Content.DataContext.Text1, RelativeSource={RelativeSource TemplatedParent}}" />
                    <DataGridTextColumn Header="{Binding Content.Text1, RelativeSource={RelativeSource TemplatedParent}}" />

                    <DataGridTextColumn Header="{Binding DataContext.Text1}" />
                    <DataGridTextColumn Header="{Binding Text1}" />

                    <DataGridTextColumn Header="Column End" />
                </DataGrid.Columns>
            </DataGrid>
        </ControlTemplate>
    </Window.Resources>
    <Window.DataContext>
        <local:ViewModel />
    </Window.DataContext>
    <Grid>
        <DataGrid Template="{StaticResource TableTemplate}" />
    </Grid>
</Window>
```

How can a column in the template bind to anything in the ViewModel? I cannot image this would not be possible.

---

For completeness, these are the errors logged to output. Their order does **not** correspond with the order of the XAML.

> System.Windows.Data Error: 40 : BindingExpression path error:
>   'DataContext' property not found on 'object' ''DataGridTextColumn'
>   (HashCode=28365320)'. BindingExpression:Path=DataContext.Text1;
>   DataItem='DataGridTextColumn' (HashCode=28365320); target element is
>   'DataGridTextColumn' (HashCode=28365320); target property is 'Header'
>   (type 'Object')
>
> System.Windows.Data Error: 40 : BindingExpression path error: 'Text1'
>   property not found on 'object' ''DataGridTextColumn'
>   (HashCode=54811268)'. BindingExpression:Path=Text1;
>   DataItem='DataGridTextColumn' (HashCode=54811268); target element is
>   'DataGridTextColumn' (HashCode=54811268); target property is 'Header'
>   (type 'Object')
>
> System.Windows.Data Error: 2 : Cannot find governing FrameworkElement
>   or FrameworkContentElement for target element.
>   BindingExpression:Path=DataContext.Text1; DataItem=null; target
>   element is 'DataGridTextColumn' (HashCode=55195297); target property
>   is 'Header' (type 'Object')
>
> System.Windows.Data Error: 2 : Cannot find governing FrameworkElement
>   or FrameworkContentElement for target element.
>   BindingExpression:Path=Text1; DataItem=null; target element is
>   'DataGridTextColumn' (HashCode=38845522); target property is 'Header'
>   (type 'Object')
>
> System.Windows.Data Error: 4 : Cannot find source for binding with
>   reference 'RelativeSource FindAncestor,
>   AncestorType='System.Windows.Window', AncestorLevel='1''.
>   BindingExpression:Path=DataContext.Text1; DataItem=null; target
>   element is 'DataGridTextColumn' (HashCode=2399386); target property is
>   'Header' (type 'Object')
>
> System.Windows.Data Error: 4 : Cannot find source for binding with
>   reference 'RelativeSource FindAncestor,
>   AncestorType='System.Windows.Window', AncestorLevel='1''.
>   BindingExpression:Path=Text1; DataItem=null; target element is
>   'DataGridTextColumn' (HashCode=31265986); target property is 'Header'
>   (type 'Object')
>
> System.Windows.Data Error: 2 : Cannot find governing FrameworkElement
>   or FrameworkContentElement for target element.
>   BindingExpression:Path=DataContext.Text1; DataItem=null; target
>   element is 'DataGridTextColumn' (HashCode=6837024); target property is
>   'Header' (type 'Object')
>
> System.Windows.Data Error: 2 : Cannot find governing FrameworkElement
>   or FrameworkContentElement for target element.
>   BindingExpression:Path=Text1; DataItem=null; target element is
>   'DataGridTextColumn' (HashCode=17422861); target property is 'Header'
>   (type 'Object')
>
> System.Windows.Data Error: 2 : Cannot find governing FrameworkElement
>   or FrameworkContentElement for target element.
>   BindingExpression:Path=Content.DataContext.Text1; DataItem=null;
>   target element is 'DataGridTextColumn' (HashCode=32669489); target
>   property is 'Header' (type 'Object')
>
> System.Windows.Data Error: 2 : Cannot find governing FrameworkElement
>   or FrameworkContentElement for target element.
>   BindingExpression:Path=Content.Text1; DataItem=null; target element is
>   'DataGridTextColumn' (HashCode=22361045); target property is 'Header'
>   (type 'Object')
>
> System.Windows.Data Error: 2 : Cannot find governing FrameworkElement
>   or FrameworkContentElement for target element.
>   BindingExpression:Path=DataContext.Text1; DataItem=null; target
>   element is 'DataGridTextColumn' (HashCode=7953856); target property is
>   'Header' (type 'Object')
>
> System.Windows.Data Error: 2 : Cannot find governing FrameworkElement
>   or FrameworkContentElement for target element.
>   BindingExpression:Path=Text1; DataItem=null; target element is
>   'DataGridTextColumn' (HashCode=65911433); target property is 'Header'
>   (type 'Object')

Comment: A simple `{Binding Text1}` should do it. Are you setting the `DataContext` from anywhere else?

Comment: So your `DataGrid` has in it's template another `DataGrid` ?

Comment: @MikeEason Unfortunately a simple `{Binding Text1}` does not do the trick. DataContext is only set for the Window. App.xaml & co. are standard, this is nearly all the code in the minimal example project.

Comment: @NovitchiS The template for the `DataGrid` is coming from a ResourceDictionary in the full-blown application. But even this minimalistic XAML does not work.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Set the `HeaderTemplate` for `DataGridTextColumn` as shown below

```
<DataGridTextColumn  >
    <DataGridTextColumn.HeaderTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <TextBlock Text="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource FindAncestor, AncestorType={x:Type Window}}, Path=DataContext.Text1}"></TextBlock>
        </DataTemplate>
    </DataGridTextColumn.HeaderTemplate>
</DataGridTextColumn>
```

Comment: That is nice and works! Would not have assumed that because (see my answer) `DataGridTextColumn` is not in the tree - with the `DataTemplate` for the `Header` it works, not sure why. Unfortunately I cannot use this to bind `Visibility` but that was not in my question ;)

Answer (score 0):

With all the hints I found out that `DataGridTextColumn` is neither part of the visual tree nor of the logical tree. That should be the reason why `ElementName` and `RelativeSource` do not work. This answer regarding `DataGridTextColumn` explains that and gives a possible solution with `Source` and `x:Reference`: [DataGridTextColumn Visibility Binding](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8847661/datagridtextcolumn-visibility-binding)

The answer of @Anand Murali works but cannot be applied to `Visibility` - that was not part of the question because I minimalized that away. So I accept that one and will give more information in this one.

Using `x:Reference` for `Visibility` it can turn out like:

```
<DataGridTextColumn Binding="{Binding Data.OrderNumber}" Header="Order Number" Visibility="{Binding DataContext.ShowColumnOrderNumber, Source={x:Reference LayoutRoot}, Converter={StaticResource BooleanToVisibilityConverter}}" />
```

But: I my example I use a `ControlTemplate` and to have `x:Reference` to work this template must be within a `.Resources` XAML part in the same file and cannot be in an external `ResourceDictionary`. In the latter case the reference will not work because it cannot be resolved. (If someone knows a solution to that it would be welcome)