# Bind DataGrid TextBox Enable based on Checkbox property

Tags: c#, wpf, datagrid, textbox

I have a DataGrid with a Checkbox & other Textbox.

```
   <DataGrid AutoGenerateColumns="False" Height="170" Name="dataGrid1" Width="527"  OpacityMask="#FF161A1A" BorderBrush="#FFB7B39D" Background="LightYellow" RowBackground="LightGray" AlternatingRowBackground="#FFFFFFF5" BorderThickness="10" CanUserResizeRows="False" CanUserReorderColumns="False" CanUserResizeColumns="True" CanUserSortColumns="False" FontFamily="Segoe UI" FontSize="13" CanUserAddRows="False">

       <DataGrid.Columns>
            <DataGridCheckBoxColumn Header="" Binding="{Binding BoolProperty, Mode=TwoWay}" />
            <DataGridTextColumn Header="" Binding="{Binding header}" MinWidth="108" IsReadOnly="True" />
            <DataGridTextColumn Header="Number of Cases" Binding="{Binding cases}" >
            <DataGridTextColumn.EditingElementStyle>
                  <Style TargetType="TextBox">
                        <Setter Property="IsEnabled" Value="{Binding Path=BoolProperty, Mode=TwoWay}" />
                 </Style>
           </DataGridTextColumn.EditingElementStyle>
          </DataGridTextColumn>
```

The checkboxcolumn is bind to a "BoolProperty". I want is Textbox "Number of Cases" to be disabled if the BoolProperty is false and enable if the BoolProperty is true. I tried adding the IsEnabled in TExtBox, but it doesn't work. Where am I going wrong ?

Comment: Why have you got it in editing edit style?

Comment: @MArk, after looking a lot I got this idea from this site's solution - http://wpf.codeplex.com/discussions/44656

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For an XAML only approach, use a template column instead. `IsReadOnly` [isn't bindable at the cell level](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3222856/net-v4-datagridtextcolumn-isreadonly-seems-to-be-faulty). Since that link doesn't provide implementation, I will.

```
<DataGridTemplateColumn>
    <DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <TextBlock Text="{Binding Path=myProperty}" />
        </DataTemplate>
    </DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
    <DataGridTemplateColumn.CellEditingTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <TextBox IsEnabled="{Binding Path=myBool}" Text="{Binding Path=myProperty, Mode=TwoWay}" />
        </DataTemplate>
    </DataGridTemplateColumn.CellEditingTemplate>
</DataGridTemplateColumn>
```

Comment: This makes no difference. Regardless of the checkbox is selected or not, I am able to enter value in Number of Cases textbox.  <DataGridTextColumn IsReadOnly="{Binding Path=BoolProperty}" Header="Number of Cases" Binding="{Binding cases}" />

Comment: @Tvd You're right, updated with what does work

Comment: Sorry to ask this, But where do I add this code - I mean it goes between TextBoxCol, or before DataCols or where ?  I am not efficient in this matter. Thanks.

Comment: `DataGridTemplateColumn` is its own column, like `DataGridTextColumn`

Comment: it is working, but after selecting checkbox, I got to click 3 times to textbox then can edit it. Even if I unselect the checkbox, then also am able to edit the textbox. Why this weird behavior ?

Comment: I accidently switched `CellTemplate` and `CellEditingTemplate`. See updated code

Comment: No Jim, same thing editable on 3 clicks Plus I also get "Two-way binding requires Path or XPath." error on going to a previously edited textbox.

Comment: @Tvd it sounds like you have something else coming into play here. This works perfectly for me on .net 4.5

Comment: @Tvd Theres a missing comma after `Path=myProperty` on the `Text` for `TextBox`. I added it now

Answer (score 0):

I used the `LoadingRow` event of my `DataGrid` in one project to check specific status. Maybe something like this could help:

```
void dataGrid_LoadingRow(object sender, DataGridRowEventArgs e)
{
    checkRow(e.Row);
}

private void checkRow(DataGridRow dgRow)
{
    if (dgRow == null)
        return;

    var item = dgRow.Item as MyItemClass;
    if (item != null && item.BoolProperty)
    {
        ...
    }
    else
    {
        ...
    }
}
```

In your case you can enable/disable your cell in the if-else contruct.

Hope it helps.

Comment: then what if when user selects/de-selects the checkbox at that time I don't think LoadingRow event will be executed. !!!!

Comment: That's right, then you can add a handler to the `CellEditEnding` event of your `DataGrid`, which calls the `checkRow()` function, too.