# Binding IsReadOnly using IValueConverter

Tags: c#, wpf, data-binding

Maybe I'm misunderstanding how to use an IValueConverter or data binding (which is likely), but I am currently trying to set the IsReadOnly property of a DataGridTextColumn depending on the value of a string. Here is the XAML:

```
<DataGridTextColumn Binding="{Binding Path=GroupDescription}" Header="Name"
                    IsReadOnly="{Binding Current,
                                 Converter={StaticResource currentConverter}}"/>
```

And here is my converter:

```
public class CurrentConverter : IValueConverter
{
    public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, System.Globalization.CultureInfo culture)
    {
        string s = value as string;
        if (s == "Current")
        {
            return false;
        }
        else
        {
            return true;
        }
    }

    public object ConvertBack(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, System.Globalization.CultureInfo culture)
    {
        throw new NotSupportedException();
    }
}
```

Currently, the column is always editable, the converter seems to do nothing. Does anyone have some thoughts as to why this is happening?

Comment: And what is the question/problem?

Comment: Updated the end of the question, hopefully it isn't too vague...

Comment: IsReadOnly isn't bindable. See my answer on http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18443063/bind-datagrid-textbox-enable-based-on-checkbox-property/18444724#18444724

Comment: @Shoe - `IsReadOnly` is bindable like any other DP.

Comment: @mastur - Where property `Current` lies? In your ViewModel class or underlying ItemsSource object?

Comment: @Rohit It is a DP but it is not a part of the visual tree, thus it does not receive notifications from source changes. [See this for more info](http://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/details/530280/wpf-4-vs2010-datagrid-isreadonly-does-not-work-with-binding-to-boolean-property)

Comment: @Shoe - Not lying in Visual Tree doesn't make DP non-bindable. You can always bind with it using `Freezable` object or by storing object in `Tag` and binding from there. Also check this link out [here](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/jaimer/archive/2008/11/22/forwarding-the-datagrid-s-datacontext-to-its-columns.aspx).

Comment: @Rohit it is non-bindable at the cell level. Yes, you can find a way to bind it at the column level. That's not what this question asks for.

Comment: @Rohit Current lies in the underlying ItemsSource object

Comment: @Shoe I copied the code from your answer and it works! Except that I can only input numbers, no letters. Is there any reason why that is that I am missing?

Comment: @Shoe - Statement seems legitimate now.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using converter you can use `DataTrigger` to enable\disable `DataGridCell`:

```
<DataGridTextColumn Header="Name" Binding="{Binding GroupDescription}">
    <DataGridTextColumn.CellStyle>
        <Style TargetType="DataGridCell">
            <Style.Triggers>
                <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding Current}" Value="Current">
                    <Setter Property="TextBlock.IsEnabled" Value="False" />                                    
                </DataTrigger>                              
            </Style.Triggers>
        </Style>                       
    </DataGridTextColumn.CellStyle>
</DataGridTextColumn>
```

Answer (score 0):

The value of DataGridTextColumn's **IsReadOnly** property is a global value that will effects all cells. The individual cell doesn't has its own **IsReadOnly** property.
Try create own **DependencyProperty** like this: http://blog.spencen.com/2009/04/25/readonly-rows-and-cells-in-a-datagrid.aspx