# WPF: Binding to the Binding mode

Tags: c#, wpf, data-binding, wpfdatagrid, datagridtextcolumn

In WPF I try to use databinding to define the BindingMode.

```xml
<controls:BoolToStringConverter x:Key="BoolToStringConverter" FalseValue="OneWay" TrueValue="TwoWay" />
<TextBox Text="{Binding MyText, Mode="{Binding Path=IsWriteable, Converter={StaticResource BoolToStringConverter}}" />
```

also, I've tried with a System.Windows.Data.BindingMode enum as datatype of property "MyBindingMode" and bind to this, but it isn't working either

```xml
<TextBox Text="{Binding MyText, Mode={Binding Path=MyBindingMode}}" />
```

Is there any possibility for such a binding or what is an appropriate approach to achieve this?

Edit:

actually in my context it's not an TextBox, it is a DataGridTextColumn. I've tried to bind `IsReadOnly="{Binding IsOnlyReadable}"` but that has no effect on the DataGridTextColumn. Setting it fixed to `IsReadOnly=True` works but binding it to a constantly true property doesn't have this effect.

Finally it is solved and I've used this for the Binding of a DataGridColumn: https://stackoverflow.com/a/27465022/9758687

Comment: What are you trying to achieve? If you want to make the TextBox not accept input, bind IsWriteable to the IsReadOnly property of the Textbox `<TextBox Text="{Binding MyText, Mode=TwoWays}" IsReadOnly="{Binding IsWriteable, Mode=OneWay, Converter={StaticResource BoolToNegativeConverter}}" />`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take a look at this link. This seems to be what you are looking for:
[.Net v4 DataGridTextColumn.IsReadOnly seems to be faulty](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3222856/net-v4-datagridtextcolumn-isreadonly-seems-to-be-faulty)

And this is the code that might fix your problem:

```
  <DataGridTextColumn>  
   <DataGridTextColumn.CellStyle>
   <Style>
     <Setter Property="UIElement.IsEnabled" Value="{Binding IsOnlyReadable}" />
   </Style>
  </DataGridTextColumn.CellStyle>
 </DataGridTextColumn>
```

Comment: Thanks, that was the trick. Finally i used this one: https://stackoverflow.com/a/27465022/9758687