# How to bind Itemsource of DataGridto the IsReadOnly property of the internal DataGridTextColumn?

Tags: c#, xml, wpf, datagrid, datagridtemplatecolumn

I have a DataGrid (below) that takes in `SimulatedItems` as an ItemsSource which is from my viewmodel. The `SimulatedItems` is an ObservableCollection of `SimulatedItem`. Inside `SimulatedItem` there is a variable `DriverID`, `NameID` and `Active`. Both the DataGridTextColumns below correctly reference these variables inside for Binding but for IsReadOnly it does not work. It appears `IsReadOnly` is attempting to bind to my viewmodel rather than the `SimulatedItems`. How do I get `IsReadOnly` to bind to my item from ItemsSource?

```
<DataGrid Grid.Row="1" ItemsSource="{Binding SimulatedItems}">
  <DataGrid.Columns>
    <DataGridTextColumn
      Header="NameID"
      Binding="{Binding NameID}"
      IsReadOnly="{Binding Active}">
    </DataGridTextColumn>
    <DataGridTextColumn
      Header="DriverID"
      Binding="{Binding Path=DriverID, Mode=TwoWay, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}"
      IsReadOnly="{Binding Active}">
    </DataGridTextColumn>
  </DataGrid.Columns>
</DataGrid>
```

Comment: What is the datatype of the Active property. Is it a string or a boolean.

Comment: It is a boolean

Comment: If i read your question correctly then this article on stackoverflow may help. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3222856/datagridtextcolumn-isreadonly-seems-to-be-faulty

Comment: This solution still causes the cell to look at my viewmodel rather than my SimulatedItem from SimulatedItems

Comment: How is the columns supposed to bind to a property of an individual item? Do you want to enable or disable the whole column?

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately this will not work.

DataContexts do not work with DataGridColumns. The binding can't find the datacontext.

Read more about it here
https://thomaslevesque.com/2011/03/21/wpf-how-to-bind-to-data-when-the-datacontext-is-not-inherited/

Solution:
Use templates

```
<DataGrid Grid.Row="1" ItemsSource="{Binding SimulatedItems}">
     <DataGrid.Columns>
           <DataGridTemplateColumn Header="NameID" Width="200">
                 <DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
                      <DataTemplate>
                          <TextBox Text="{Binding NameID}" IsReadOnly="{Binding  Active}" BorderThickness="0" Background="Transparent"/>
                      </DataTemplate>
                 </DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
            </DataGridTemplateColumn>
            <DataGridTemplateColumn Header="DriverID" Width="200">
                  <DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
                         <DataTemplate>
                             <TextBox Text="{Binding Path=DriverID, Mode=TwoWay, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}" IsReadOnly="{Binding Active}" BorderThickness="0" Background="Transparent"/>
                         </DataTemplate>
                  </DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
            </DataGridTemplateColumn>
     </DataGrid.Columns>
</DataGrid>
```